# Checkerboard with row and columns

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I looked for the answeer and i find nothing about it.
So my question is how can i make a checkerboard with just using js. When i open the site, it should askes the user how many rows and columns they want to have so if i say 5 rows and 5 columns it should generate a checkerboard with this. I should use a for-loop and if for this.
Heres my Code i worked on.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      var row = prompt("Rows?", 10);
      row = parseInt(row);
      var column = prompt("Columns?", 10);
      column = parseInt(column);

      for(var i= 1;i<=column;i++)
      {
        for(var p= 1;p<=row;p++)
        {
          if(p % 2 == 0)
          {
            document.write(' <img src="schwarz.png" ' + "<br />");

        {

          document.write(' <img src="weiss.png" ' + "<br />");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only real issue with your code is that you're not applying 'float: left' to the elements. Also, use 'clear: both' to make an element go to a new line. Here's an example.

```
var rows = prompt('Rows?', 10);
var cols = prompt('Columns?', 10);

var templateBlock = '<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; float: left; background-color: $COLOR$;""></div>';

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        var template = templateBlock.replace('$COLOR$', ((i + j) % 2) ? 'white' : 'black');

        if (j == 0)
            template = template.replace('style="', 'style="clear: both; ');

        document.write(template);
    }
}
```